# find nested boxes from huge dataset with geopandas (or other tools)

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, bounding-box

Basically I have `DataFrame` with a huge amount of boxes which are defined with  `xmin`     `ymin`  `xmax`  `ymax` tuples.

```
    xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
0   66      88      130     151
1   143     390     236     468
2   77      331     143     423
3   289     112     337     157
4   343     282     405     352
.....
```

My task is to remove all nested boxes. (I.e. any box which is `within` another box has to be removed)

My current method:

- construct GeoDataFrame with box geometry
- sort by box size (descending)
- iteratively find smaller boxes within a larger box.

Sandbox: https://www.kaggle.com/code/easzil/remove-nested-bbox/

```
def remove_nested_bbox(df):
  # make an extra unique 'id'
  df['__id'] = range(0, len(df))
  # create geometry
  df['__geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.box(x.xmin, x.ymin, x.xmax, x.ymax), axis=1)
  gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='__geometry')
  # sort by area
  gdf['__area'] = gdf.__geometry.area
  gdf.sort_values('__area', ascending=False, inplace=True)

  nested_id = set()
  for iloc in range(len(gdf)):
    # skip aready identifed one
    if gdf.iloc[iloc]['__id'] in nested_id:
      continue
    bbox  = gdf.iloc[iloc]    # current target larger bbox
    tests = gdf.iloc[iloc+1:] # all bboxes smaller than the urrent target 
    tests = tests[~tests['__id'].isin(nested_id)] # skip aready identifed one
    nested = tests[tests['__geometry'].within(bbox['__geometry'])]
    nested_id.update(list(nested['__id']))
    
  df = df[~df['__id'].isin(nested_id)]
  
  del df['__id']
  del df['__geometry']
  del df['__area']
    
  return df
```

Is there any better way to optimize the task to make it faster?
The current method is pretty slow to handle large dataset.

I would also consider other methods such as implementing in C or CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your sample data is not large and has no instances of boxes within boxes.  Have generated some randomly
- have used approach of using `loc` checking dimensions are bigger
- not sure if this is faster than your approach, timing details

```
%timeit gdf["within"] = gdf.apply(within, args=(gdf,), axis=1)
print(f"""number of polygons: {len(gdf)}
number kept: {len(gdf.loc[lambda d: ~d["within"]])}
""")
```

```
2.37 s ± 118 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
number of polygons: 2503
number kept: 241
```

#### visuals

[image]

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import io
import shapely

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """    xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
0   66      88      130     151
1   143     390     236     468
2   77      331     143     423
3   289     112     337     157
4   343     282     405     352"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

# randomly generate some boxes, check they are valid
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 200, [10000, 4]), columns=["xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"]
).loc[lambda d: (d["xmax"] > d["xmin"]) & (d["ymax"] > d["ymin"])]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=df.apply(lambda r: shapely.geometry.box(*r), axis=1)
)

gdf.plot(edgecolor="black", alpha=0.6)

# somewhat optimised by limiting polygons that are considered by looking at dimensions
def within(r, gdf):
    for g in gdf.loc[
        ~(gdf.index == r.name)
        & gdf["xmin"].lt(r["xmin"])
        & gdf["ymin"].lt(r["ymin"])
        & gdf["xmax"].gt(r["xmax"])
        & gdf["ymax"].gt(r["ymax"]),
        "geometry",
    ]:
        if r["geometry"].within(g):
            return True
    return False


gdf["within"] = gdf.apply(within, args=(gdf, ), axis=1)

gdf.loc[lambda d: ~d["within"]].plot(edgecolor="black", alpha=0.6)
```

#### approach 2

- using sample data you provided on kaggle
- this returns in about half the time (5s) compared to previous version
- concept is similar, a box is within another box if xmin & ymin are greater than that of another box and max & ymax are less

```
import functools

df = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/2015126/3336994/sample.csv?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220322%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220322T093633Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=3cc7824afe45313fe152858a6b8d79f93b0d90237ad82737fcf28949b9314df4be2f247821934a371d09cff4b463d69fc2422d8d7f746d6fccf014605b2e0f2cba54c23fba012c2531c4cd714436545bd83db0e880072fa049b116106ba4e296c259c32bc19267a15b9b9af78494bb6859cb53ffe4388c3b8c375a330e09008bb1d9c839f8ab4c14a8f01c38179ba31dc9f4ea9fa11f5ecc7e6ba87757edbe48577d60988349b948ceb70e885be5d6ebc36abe438a5275fa683ee4e318e21661ea032af7d8e2f488020288a1a2ff15af8aa153bb8ac33a0b827dd53c928ddf3abb024f2972ba6ef21bc9a0034e504706a2b3fc78be9ea3bb9190437d98a8ab35")

def within_np(df):
    d = {}
    for c in df.columns[0:4]:
        a = np.tile(df[c].values.T ,(len(df),1))
        d[c] = a.T > a if c[1:] == "min" else a.T < a

    aa = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, (aa for aa in d.values()))
    return aa.sum(axis=1)>0

df.loc[~within_np(df)]
```

Comment: unfortunately not really better. but still thanks for the idea :)

Comment: I added a sample dataset and create a sandbox https://www.kaggle.com/code/easzil/remove-nested-bbox/ to test it.

Comment: the data is showing as private on kaggle so I can't access it.... can you make it accessible?

Comment: OK, it is made public now.

Comment: have provided another approach that runs in about half the time

Comment: wow, it is really fast!! the simple operation is indeed much faster than geometry operation. does pandas compute in parallel?

Comment: no it's not parallel,  but it is a vectorised solution

Comment: thanks, I learned something :)